# Does the metric in the Theory of Relativity actually satisfy the definition of a metric?

Tags: metric-spaces, definition, general-relativity

Allow me to give a brief introduction to the topic, which has to do with physics; my question will still be a mathematical one. I think my question is aimed at people with a background both in physics and in mathematics.

I am familiar with the Theory of Relativity, in which *spacetime* is described as a four-dimensional manifold with a notion of distance (invariant under the Poincare group). This distance is described by an object that is called the *metric* or the *metric tensor*. A simple example of such a metric is the Minkowski metric. This metric (tensor) is (at least as evaluated in some coordinate frame and up to certain conventions) described by the 4x4 matrix $\eta = diag(-1,1,1,1)$. As a result, the spacetime distance between two points $x,y$, described by their components $x^\mu, y^\mu$, $(\mu=0,1,2,3)$, is given by
\begin{equation}
d(x,y)=\eta_{\mu\nu} (x^\mu - y^\mu)(x^\nu - y^\nu)~,
\end{equation}
where summation over repeated indices is implied. Now comes my question. When we take $x$ and $y$ to be given, for instance, by $x = (2,0,0,0)$ and $y=(1,0,0,0)$, then we arrive at a negative distance:
\begin{equation}
d(x,y) = -1~.
\end{equation}
Now, regarding the Theory of Relativity, this is quite possible, but recently I came across the formal definition of a metric. And one of the conditions stated that **a metric maps each pair of points in the space to a non-negative real number**. But in our example of the Minkowski metric, this is clearly not the case. So the Minkowski metric does not seem to satisfy the definition of a metric.

So, is the metric in the Theory of Relativity just a different kind of metric, or does it have to do with a distinction between metrics and metric tensors? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: u have to discern between usual riemannian manifolds (like euclidian space) and pseudo-riemannian manifolds (like minkowsiki space) where the notation of distance becomes a litte bit more tricky then ususal

Comment: "Minkowski metrics" and "topological metrics" (as one might call them) are simply incompatible concepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Metric in the sense of [metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) and metrics in the sense of [(pseudo)Riemannian metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) are very distinct concepts. It is one of the cases where the limits of language causes two or more distinct concepts to share one name. For other instances of this in mathematics consider the word "normal" or the word "distribution".

Answer (score -2):

It is not a metric because, as you say, distance must be positive. So they use a different word for negative distance, called pseudometric distance. That is, the interval is not called a metric, it's called a **pseudometric.** That distinction is the most important fact in special relativity, %he most important concept in understanding what space and time really are.

Comment: Now, why would anybody downvote that?

Comment: because it's not a pseudometric

Comment: You don't think the spacetime interval is a pseudometric. Really?

Comment: A pseudometric is a metric without the degeneracy condition. Two points can be zero distance apart in a pseudometric. That's also true of the Minkowski metric (any two light-like points have zero distance). But that's where the similarities end. Pseudometrics still have to satisfy the triangle rule. Minkowski metric doesn't. Pseudometrics are still real valued functions, whereas Minkowski metric if you insisted on viewing it as a function (which people usually do not), it would be complex valued.

Comment: Which brings up the other way your answer is wrong: spacetime interval squared can be negative. But spacetime interval itself would then be pure imaginary, the square root of a negative. You talk about negative distances but there are no negative distances in Minkowski geometry. So it cannot be the most important concept in understanding what space, time and the universe really are

Comment: [JEE-ziss...]
1. Don't wow me with jargon. I don't get blinded by science.

Comment: 2. That includes the nominal distinction between "pseudometric" and "Minkowskian." SHEE-yit.

Comment: 3. Yes the 4D distance can be purely imaginary. But ct² is not, and that is the "time distance" -- positive elapsed time -- that gets SUBTRACTED from the spatial distance.  One nanosecond of elapsed time is negative 12 inches.The metric says so, whether you call it ""Lorentzian" or "pseudometric" or "The Einstein metric." ct² "behaves" like negative spatial distance in the equation.

Comment: 4.It's why the null cone is null.

Comment: the quantity $\Delta s^2 = \Delta ct^2 - \Delta x^2 - \Delta y^2 - \Delta z^2$ is called spacetime interval. It's not a metric. It's not a pseudometric. But it can be negative. But I would agree that it's the more important concept.